# Passing an object to an included file oop php

Tags: php, oop, object, include, scope

I'm developing a cms and I want the designer to be able to call all of the content while using an object called $view. My problem is that the included template-file can't access the $view-object anymore.

The view object contains stuff like page_title(),... etc. 
I also work with templates, so I want the designer to be able to call for the right template by accessing the $view object.

Some code to backup my explanation:

My library:

```
class view {
    function page_title() {}

    function template() {
       $this->template = new template;
       $this->template_include = $this->template->template_include();
    }
}

class template {
    function template_include(){
       include('template.php');
    }
}
```

My index-file:

```
$view = new view;
$view->template();
```

My template.php:

```
$view->page_title();
```

But I encountered a problem: The view object is created, then is, with a method from the view class, called for an object that, with the method template_include(), includes the right template.php. In this template I use the view-object again, in order to call for the right titles, content,...
My problem is that the included template-file can't access the $view-object anymore.

Guess you all know the error: 
    Fatal error: Call to a member function field_title() on a non-object

I'm devoted to make this cms as easy as possible for the designer/user, so I only want the view-object to call for everything, without extra includes in the template-file etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the `$view` to the method/class

Index

```
 $view = new view;
 $view->template($view);
```

Classes

```
 class view {
    function page_title() { echo "this works!!!";}

    function template($view) {
       $this->template = new template;
       $this->template_include = $this->template->template_include($view);
    }
}

class template {
    function template_include($view){
       include('template.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. It's my first time OOP php, so I hope I didn't bother you all with this (seemingly simple?) question.

Comment: no problem at all.. using php you can also pass the variable by reference by using `&` before the variable name in function definition... `function template(&$view)` but in this situation you should not use it...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to globally declare the $view-object?

Put `global $view;` in both your `index.php` as well as `template.php`, hopefully it resolves your issue!

Comment: Thanks, but, I tried it, and it doesn't work. As a test I tried it with objects and 'normal' includes (not included in a method), and this works normally. But off course, that's not wat I want :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are including template file  inside a function, contents of this file is interpreted with the scope of this function. The best way to solve it will be to pass associative array to this function with variables that you want to have in this scope, ie:

```
class view {
    function page_title() {}

    function template(array $variables) {
       $this->template = new template;
       $this->template_include = $this->template->template_include($variables);
    }
}

class template {
    function template_include(array $variables){
        if($variables){
            extract($variables);
        }
        include('template.php');
    }
}
```

Now by calling it like this, you will have access to `$view` and `$title` variables inside your template:

```
$view = new view;
$vars = array(
    'view' => $view,
    'title' => 'some title'
);
$view->template($vars);
```